# What is the name of a grammar which can change its tokenizer in mid parse?

Tags: terminology, parsing, lexer

I was creating a language and discovered that my language tokenizer would have to change depending where in the parse it is.

I.e. `abc[1]` would be parsed as 4 tokens (`abc`, `[`, `1`, `]`), where as `{ abc[1] }` would be parsed as 3 (`{`, `abc[1]`, `}`).

Is a grammar that would change its tokenizer mid parse defined somewhere? Does a grammar even define such a thing or is it irrelevant to the grammar and is just not really done on a parser level?

Comment: Is `{ abc[1] }` supposed to be something like a string literal?

Comment: I have read of a term for doing something like this in the lexer.  Sadly I don't currently remember either the name or anything helpful to look it up (well, it was a Martin Fowler signature series book).

Comment: Typically, one would tokenize `{ abc[1]}` as '{', 'abc', '[', '1', ']', '}'.  The parser would then handle - that `abc[1]` isn't a token.

Comment: @Blrfl, not exactly.  The braces indicate that the tokens are whitespace delimited.

Comment: -1ing without stating a reason is useless.  Could you please explain?

Comment: (I am not the downvoter) - this likely stems from "is unclear" or for that matter "it is not useful." Asking for a name for something isn't terribly useful.  Asking how to handle a parser is more useful. Describing the nature of the tokenizer/parser, the problem you are encountering, and your desired end result may make the question more clear and useful to other people (rather than just asking for a name of it).

Comment: To be picky, a _grammar_ doesn't have a tokeniser. A _parser_ has a tokeniser.

Comment: @Adrian: you don't have to change anything mid-stream to do what you're describing.  The bracket syntax in the parser would just be any different than handling the comma-delimited version in C or the `qw()` construct in Perl.  Whether the items in the list are string literals or expressions, you can arrange the parser grammar to handle them.  The lexer just has to be smart enough not to group things into tokens prematurely.

Comment: @FrankShearar, that is what I thought, but wasn't sure.

Comment: @MichaelT, I'm not sure about it being unclear.  Could you expand on that?  As for not being useful, I wanted to be able to describe what I was doing to others with a particular name if it existed, and since there is a `terminology` tag, I think that this is relevant.

Comment: @Blrfl, comma-delimited version in C is different. The token definition doesn't change in such a list. This is like the qw() construct in Perl.   How would premature tokenization be avoided?

Comment: @Adrian:  Don't tokenize things that that resemble identifiers (e.g., `abc`) in the lexer.  Define those things in the grammar and the parser will sort things out correctly.

Comment: @Blrfl: Yeah, could do.  Would require reassembling the tokens back into a single token though.  And how would you distinguish between a sub token and the next real token?  (i.e. `{ abc[1] [4] }` would be 4 tokens (`{`, `abc[1]`, `[4]`, `}`))  Maybe I should start a new question for this though as I think this is getting OT from the original question.

Comment: @Blrf: I've created a new question for this [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/198399/is-it-possible-to-create-a-single-tokenizer-to-parse-this).

Comment: @FrankShearar, your right a grammar has tokens, not a tokenizer. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no special name for this type of grammar that I know of. What you have there is still a LR(k) grammar that could be parsed by a parser that takes each character to be a token, and has k characters of lookahead.

The division of parsing into tokenization and syntax recognition stems from the desire to increase efficiency by reducing lookahead to 1 symbol. (That and the fact that a token is a concept in the syntax of a programming language, so why not have a matching representation in the language implementation.)

That is to say, the principal technical advantage of parsing tokens rather than characters is that we can distinguish `interface` and `integer` with one symbol of lookahead rather than three symbols of lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

Separate tokenizers are an implementation detail of parsers.  Separate tokenizers are not necessary; it is possible to create parsers without separate tokenizers.

However, separate tokenizers are often used in practice, and when they are, the tokens are often defined using (real) [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) expressions.

If you're using a separate tokenizer, you may find it difficult or impossible to switch tokenizers in the middle of a parse.  However, there are no theoretical problems with doing this, just technological -- if you choose the right technology, it's actually quite easy to do.

So to answer your specific questions:

- "Is a grammar that would change it's tokenizer mid parse defined somewhere?" This can happen with language composition.  Separate, regular tokenizers do not interact well with language composition.
- "Does a grammar even define such a thing or is it irrelevant to the grammar and is just not really done on a parser level?"  Tokenization is a part of a grammar, so yes, a grammar is free to dictate how tokenization occurs depending on what rule it's trying to parse.  However, you may not see this often in practice.  Typically, at least in my experience, tokenization is regular and not context-free or context-sensitive.